# Correct compiler terminology

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, linker, preprocessor, terminology

I'm coding a compiler that consists of four separate programs: the preprocessor, the to-assembly compiler, the assembler (NASM) and the linker (ld).

When writing about it, I have some issues expressing the exact part of the compiler I'm referring to; i.e., when I just type "the compiler", it could mean either the whole program chain that is invoked by a single command (like GCC), or the actual compiler that converts a translation unit into NASM.

What is the correct terminology here? Should I refer to the inner ("true") compiler as "translator" or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that, rather than looking for "correct" terminology (subjective at best), you should instead aim for consistent terminology and explain early on what the terms means.

For *example,* call the entire thing a toolchain and each component of it something more specific:

> The xyzzy toolchain contained in this package consists of four components:
>
> - the preprocessor;
> - the compiler;
> - the assembler; and
> - the linker.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make it too complicated. You should be straightforward and refer to the to-assembly compiler as the compiler. GCC stands for GNU Compiler Collection, so I would say something like "compiler system" when you want to refer to the entire set of programs.

Comment: And on that note, you could really call each part by any name as long as you state it earlier somewhere. e.g. "The to-assembly compiler, from here forth referred to as the Unicorn, is used..."